# Undefined values when using map array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, undefined

I have a problem when trying to get values from object and pass it to child. 
This is my code :

```
let listDomestic = this.state.domesticArray.map((item) => 
      <DomesticItem 
        key={item.id}
        index={item.index}
        deleteMethod={() => this.deleteDomesticElement(key)}
      />
    );
```

the problem is on `key={item.id}` and `index={item.index}`, so `key` and `index` are undefined, I see this by printing them in child

My function to add objects in `domesticArray` is like so:

```
addDomesticItem() {
    let id = Date.now();
    let index = this.state.domesticArray.length;
    let newItem = {
      id: id,
      index: index,
      quantity: 0,
      watt: 0,
      duration: 0,
      whDay: 0,
    }

    let newDomesticArray = [...this.state.domesticArray];
    newDomesticArray.push({
      newItem
    });

    this.setState({
      domesticArray: newDomesticArray
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is creating a new object and setting `newItem` as a *property* on it (the property's name is `newItem`, you're using shorthand property notation unintentionally), then pushing that new item into the array.

The minimal change is to change this:

```
newDomesticArray.push({
  newItem
});
```

to this:

```
newDomesticArray.push(newItem);
```

**But**:

1. You need to use the callback version of `setState`, not the version you pass an object to. That's because you're setting *new* state based on *existing* state, and [state updates are asynchronous and may be combined][1].
2. We can make that more concise. :-)

So just addressing those two things, and using parameter destructuring:

```
addDomesticItem() {
    this.setState(({domesticArray}) => {
        const newItem = {
          id: Date.now(),
          index: domesticArray.length,
          quantity: 0,
          watt: 0,
          duration: 0,
          whDay: 0,
        };
        return {domesticArray: [...domesticArray, newItem]};
    });
}
```

**But** (part 2):

3. I recommend that you don't rely on `Date.now` for `id`. If you ever end up adding two items within the same millisecond (remember, computers are **fast**), they won't have unique IDs.
4. I recommend that you don't include the index of the item in the array in the item itself, since it makes maintaining the entries in the array difficult.

Instead, I'd have an ever-increasing counter in your component that you use for `id` values. In your constructor:

```
this.idAllocator = 0;
```

and then:

```
addDomesticItem() {
    this.setState(({domesticArray}) => {
        const newItem = {
          id: ++this.idAllocator,
          quantity: 0,
          watt: 0,
          duration: 0,
          whDay: 0,
        };
        return {domesticArray: [...domesticArray, newItem]};
    });
}
```

and then:

```
let listDomestic = this.state.domesticArray.map((item, index) => 
      <DomesticItem 
        key={item.id}
        deleteMethod={() => this.deleteDomesticElement(key)}
      />
    );
```

and then when you need to find the item in `this.state.domesticArray`, you use `find`:

```
const item = this.state.domesticArray.find(item => item.id === id);
```

or `findIndex` to find its index:

```
const index = this.state.domesticArray.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
```

and remember that if you're going to use that `index` to modify `domesticArray`, you need to do that in a `setState` callback.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder, useful recommendations